# how to set keybinds to disable in viewport and render blender 3.0

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, customization

I'm looking for a way to set keybinds for disable in viewport and disable in render because I have a ton of selected objects that I would like to disable all at once. I cant find the option for these 2 in the keymap tab in preferences and there isn't an assign shortcut option when I right-click the icons. How do I do this?

Comment: The easiest option would be - but that's not working very well if you are using different collections to structure your scene - to put all objects, which you want to be able to hide all in viewport and render at once, in a single collection and then disable this with the checkmark in the outliner. Just note: if you have hidden objects in this collection by using the eye symbol, they reappear as soon as you enable the collection again. The eye symbol is a kind of temporary hiding. If you want some objects to stay hidden no matter if the collection is enabled, you have to use the screen symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Disable Visibility of all selected object

`Alt` `Left Click` the button

[image]

There are no shortcut on default, you need make a addon to do that.